# Wpf ListView Is it possible to order the group items differently from the group headers?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a List View Control with grouping and sorting.

The group headers are Dates in descending order.

I am trying to find out how to order the grouped items under each group header in an ascending order, but cant figure out how to get it done or if it is even possible with ListView.

Here is the XAML I have so far.

Note: ScheduledItemSearchResults is an observable collection of ScheduleItems each item has a Title and a ScheduleDate property.

```
<Grid x:Name="TxScheduleItemResults"
              Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding ScheduledItemSearchResults}" x:Key="scheduledItems">
                    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Value.ScheduleDateTime" Direction="Descending"/>
                    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                        <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Value.ScheduleDateTime.Date" />
                    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                </CollectionViewSource>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <ListView x:Name="ScheduledItemResultsList"
                      Style="{StaticResource TransparentListViewStyle}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingListViewItemStyle}" 
                      AlternationCount="2"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource scheduledItems}}"
                      >

                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Scheduled Items"
                                        Width="{Binding ElementName=ScheduledItemResultsList, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                        >
                            <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ModuleGroupHeader}"
                                               Text="{Binding}"
                                               />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value.Title}" Width="200"/>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value.ScheduleDateTime, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm:ss}}" Width="120"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Path=Items[0].Value.ScheduleDateTime.Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                        <TextBlock Text=" item(s)" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Expander>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: `SortDescriptions` should work for sorting groups and items in groups. What's wrong with it?

Comment: The Sort description sorts all items in the collection in date descending order This causes the group headers to be sorted correctly. But  I want to sort the Items under each group in Date Ascending order.   So I want a different sort description!? for items in each group.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can have several `SortDescriptions` elements in one `CollectionViewSource`:

```
 <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding ScheduledItemSearchResults}" x:Key="scheduledItems">
                <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    <!--This will sort groups-->
                    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Value.ScheduleDateTime.Date" />
                    <!--This will items-->
                    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Value.ScheduleDateTime" Direction="Descending"/>
                </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Value.ScheduleDateTime.Date" />
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
```

P.S. I don't quite get how exactly you want to sort it, but if you sort first groups and then items it should work.

Comment: Thank you,  This was the inverse of the sorting I was after but it is the correct answer.